# Unable to update the labels of the x, y axis and the main plot area

Tags: r, plot, label

I am trying to plot a time series graph but the labels of the xaxis, yaxis and the  main area won't change. What I can do right in the following code?How do I set the max and min value of the y-axis?

```
plot(gfit.acc1, which = 3, type ="l", col= "lightblue", 
   xlab= "3 * GARCHSTD, SP RETURNS, -3 * GARCHSTD" , main ="GARCH volatilities")
```

Comment: `plot` is a generic function - there are different methods for different data types.  What does `class(gfit.acc1)` return?  (The question would be improved if you included code for us to reproduce the object too.)

Comment: gfit.acc1 is a timeseries vector

Answer (score 0):

To set the max and min value or `x-axis` or `y-axis`, use `xlim` and `ylim` in `plot.window`.

Adding to your code,

```
plot(gfit.acc1, which = 3, type ="l", col= "lightblue", 
   xlab= "3 * GARCHSTD, SP RETURNS, -3 * GARCHSTD" , main ="GARCH volatilities"
   plot.window(xlim=c(low, high), ylim=c(high,low)))
```

For more information, check `?plot` and `?plot.window`

PS: Answered this question with the understanding that, you need to know how to set up min and max values for axes.

Comment: Thanks Manoj, Can you still let me know why the xlab and main is not appearing in the plot. And I do not know how to set the max and min values of axes. Can you please still help me with my query?

Comment: @SudiptaBanerjee: As @richie-cotton mentioned, update your question with the result of, `class(gfit.acc1)`. Then only we could figure out why `xlab` and `ylab` are not appearing in your plot. For setting max and min values of axes, use `plot.window()` function as above, replace `low` and `high` in the above answer with your max and min value..

Comment: @ManojG I think he is saying he wants to manually change the labels / titles on the plot (hence, his use of `xlab =`, `main = ` in his original code). My guess is that the class of the object is a "decomposed.ts". I've noticed that whenever I try to change the title when using `plot()` on a decomposed.ts object, I get an error message. That may be what the OP is asking: how to change the main title and x- and y-axis labels when using `plot()` on a decomposed time-series object.